# How can I create simple upload interface with html (and possibly bash)?

Tags: networking, bash, transfer

I'm trying to share files quickly between 2 of my Ubuntu PCs (on the same network). So instead of doing scp everytime, I installed webfsd (lighter than apache) on both computers. Whenever I need to transfer a file, I just open that folder and run `webfsd -p 8080` on one computer and on other computer open link (192.168.x.x) from browser and download whatever files I need from that location.

Now, I want to make this system somewhat more efficient. So I want to do it with webfsd installed only on 1 computer (say A). So when I need to transfer files from A to B, I would run that command from the specific folder and happily download the files from B. Now how can I transfer files from B to A without using running webfsd on B? What I want is just some upload interface that I can access from the browser (say by typing `192.168.x.x/upload.html`). Is that possible without running php on host machine (A)? Is it possible with a simple Bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html is just a passive document and will not change anything on the server. So the answer is: No.

More details: [Simple HTML upload form Without PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772230/simple-html-upload-form-without-php)

Comment: Can we use shell script to handle the upload instead of php?

Comment: No. Webfs is for purely static content.